# mkdir: cannot create directory `../abc/2011-11-23: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, sftp

I have got a sftp script that downloads the archives , unzip it and then rename the files according to date and moves it to respective folder.

I had to move the script from USB drive onto a separate server . After i moved whenever the script runs it extracts the files but while moving files it gives following error :

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `../abc/2011-11-23': No such file or directory
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the 'directory' you are currently in happen to be a symlink to somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `abc` folder doesn't exist. You probably want to use `-p` option to make parent directories as needed:

```
$ mkdir -p ../abc/2011-11-23
```

Comment: thats what confusing me as /abc folder is already there, but i am still going try this

Answer (score 1):

Either there is no '../' or there is no '../abc/'