# mkdir: cannot create directory 'html': No such file or directory

Tags: centos

I  accidentally deleted the directory /var/www/html on a CentOS server, however the directory /var/www still exists. I cd'd into the directory /var/www and tried to create the directory html with the below command:

```
mkdir html
```

Unfortunately, this gives me this error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory 'html': No such file or directory
```

I have searched for solutions to this, yet every Stack Overflow page I find says this is due to the parent folder not existing, such as the below. This is not my case however, as I am creating the child folder html from directly within www, with no parent folder being specified. I also tried the '-p' flag that is suggested, and get the same error.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/690702/no-such-file-or-directory-mkdir
[mkdir: cannot create directory `../abc/2011-11-23: No such file or directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/336908/mkdir-cannot-create-directory-abc-2011-11-23-no-such-file-or-directory)
I tried restarting the httpd service, yet get this error:

```
DocumentRoot '/var/www/html' is not a directory, or is not readable
```

I suspect it may be a permission issue, however I am logged in as root when doing this, and have full permission on the 'var/www' folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  0 root www-data    0 Aug  8 11:42 www
```

Comment: did you tried `mkdir /var/www/html`

Comment: late but, did you find a solution? :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and this was my checklist (for future reference):

- (as you already said) parent directory not existent
- you have no permissions to the file-system
- the file-system is mounted read-only (this was it for me, even though I mounted it with `-o rw`)